Optimize in defining table in dbt
in schema.yml of dbt , i defined a column like this :
models:
  - name: tt1
    description: "table for sale information"
    columns: *inv

the problem is that i have many table have the same columns like tt1 , tt2 ,... . So i have used loop
models:
  {% for i in range(0, var('ninv')|int +1) %}
  - name: tonkho{{i}}
    description: "This table contains details inventory"
    columns: *inv
  {% endfor %}

and it return error
models:
dbt-1                   |     70 |   {% for i in range(0, var('ninv')+1) %}
dbt-1                   |     71 |   - name: tt{{i}}
dbt-1                   |     72 |     description: "This table contains sale information"
dbt-1                   |     73 |     columns: *inv

it seems like the yaml file doesn't accept the jinja.

If you only want to generate YML for your model , then have a look at codegen.generate_model_yml utility. This will automatically generate the YML file and you can then use it directly.
